# https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/ kill alive session

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, oauth

I am localy developing a cordova hybrid app, i called the https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/ to get the access token
First time it works fine and opened the fb login page

But now I am "facebook wise" logged-in, in my app and cant log out

I have not stored the access-token anywhere, I keep refreshing the app while modifying existing code

So each time I click on my login to fb button nothing happens.

how can I get out of this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in to www.facebook.com (with the same user) and go to Settings -> Apps and remove the respective app from your user's profile. That should help.

Killing cookies is no option based on you're using a Cordova app.

Comment: that's not logging out or "kill alive session"

Comment: That's not his problem... Once he gave his permissions, he is logged in into the app, which can be removed with my described solution. He's not using a normal browser, but a Cordova app, so "killing the cookies" is no option

Comment: Thx I gonna try this, sounds like a very good idea. but how could I avoid this problem in the future ? 
How to correctly store the acccess-token to be available all the time

Comment: That's not really what you asked in your question. What do you want to do, store Access Tokens, or remove the app from the User's profile? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/#class_methods

Comment: No the answer was perfect, i just want to avoid this happening again now. Maybe I should create another question about that